# Inspect / disassemble .Net native images

Tags: .net, disassembly, ngen

Is it possible to disassemble / inspect the native code produced by the .Net JITer / ngen? (for purely academic purposes)

In attempting to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191526/how-long-does-it-take-to-invoke-an-empty-function) I became intrigued about what sort of optimisations the JITer would perform - rather than speculate wildly I'd really like to be able to see for myself what is really hapenning.

So far I've:

1. Installed a native image of my candidate assembly using [ngen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (is the output of this potentially different from the output of the JIT compiler?)
2. Copied the native image out of the GAC

But now I'm a bit stuck - as far as I was aware .Net assemblies are in the [portable execuable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) format, but the normal tools that I might use to disassemble such a file (objdump) just barf:

```
C:\Users\justin\Desktop>objdump -d ConsoleApplication1.ni.exe
objdump: ConsoleApplication1.ni.exe: File format not recognized
```

Is it feasible to peek inside a native image in this way?  Failing that is there some alternative way that I might be able to satisfy my curiosity? (for example disassembling the code in a running process)

Comment: I got some useful techniques when I asked [Is there a way to see the native code produced by theJITter for given C# / CIL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945719/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-native-code-produced-by-thejitter-for-given-c-cil)

Comment: Can't you take a look with windbg, or dumpbin?

Comment: @AakashM Very useful and probably more reliable than inspecing native images!

Comment: No problem :) Actually, I might even add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some success with windbg and [dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in the past, when trying this sort of thing.